# What does the question mark in type definitions do?

Tags: typescript, knex.js, typescript-generics

I was looking through the Nest.js type definitions because Typescript was demanding a specific type in my argument.

```js
insert<TResult2 = number[]>(
  data: TRecord extends CompositeTableType<unknown>
    ? ResolveTableType<TRecord, 'insert'> | ReadonlyArray<ResolveTableType<TRecord, 'insert'>>
    : DbRecordArr<TRecord> | ReadonlyArray<DbRecordArr<TRecord>>
): QueryBuilder<TRecord, TResult2>;
```

In this function, what does the `?` do after the `CompositeTableType` type. I know the `|` bar specifies that either `ResolveTableType` or `ReadonlyArray` need to be used but have no idea how that'd tie in with the `?`.

**The function in question that I was making**

```js
async create(data: TTableAttributes extends any) // Put any because wasn't sure what to put after "extends CompositeTableType<TTableAttributes>"
{
    await this.knex.insert(data).returning("*").then((data) => { console.log(data); return data; });
}
```

Comment: Isnt this just a ternary *condition ? Exp1 : exp2*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called **Conditional Types**. It's just a regular conditional operator (ternary operator ?:)
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

If TRecord inherits from CompositeTableType then "data" parameter would be of type **ResolveTableType<TRecord, 'insert'> | ReadonlyArray<ResolveTableType<TRecord, 'insert'>>**. Otherwise, it would be of type **DbRecordArr | ReadonlyArray<DbRecordArr>**